# Particular records does not show up in Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display a particular record in a model pop up for editing purpose, below is the code I am using. Modal pop up opens but it only shows the first record. I don't know how can I pass id of a product which the user clicks on the same page where I am calling myModal.
Please give me some hints about how to solve this problem.

View_product.php

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
              <?php
 $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_product";
 $sql_q=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q))
    {
    $productid=$row['pid'];
    $prodName= $row['product_name']; 
    $prodPrice= $row['product_price']; 

 ?>
              <tr class="odd">
                <td class=" sorting_1"><?=$prodName?></td>
                <td class="center "><?=$prodPrice?></td>
                <td class="center "> <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDetail" href="#myModalDetail"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a> </td>
              </tr>

              <? } ?>
            </tbody>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModalDetail">
  <?php require "edit_products.php"; ?>
</div>
```

edit_products.php

```
    <?php

     $productid=$productid;
     $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE pid='".$productid."'";
     $sql_q=mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q))
        {
            $productid=$row['pid'];
            $prodName= $row['product_name']; 
            $prodPrice= $row['product_price']; 

        }
    ?>

        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Products</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <form role="form" name="Insertdb" method="post" action="Insert_code/edit-products.php">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Product Name</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input class="form-control" name="prodName" value="<?=$prodName ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Product Price</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                     <input class="form-control" name="prodPrice" value="<?=$prodPrice?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
        </form>
        </div>
       </div>
       <!-- /.modal-content --> 
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_product";
$sql_q=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q))
{
$productid=$row['pid'];
$prodName= $row['product_name']; 
$prodPrice= $row['product_price']; 

?>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1"><?=$prodName?></td>
        <td class="center "><?=$prodPrice?></td>
        <td class="center "> 

            <!-- change data-target -->
            <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDetail-<?=$productid?>" href="#myModalDetail">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </a> 
            <!-- change data-target -->

            <!-- place this code inside the loop -->

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDetail-<?=$productid?>">
                <?php require "edit_products.php"; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- place this code inside the loop -->

        </td>
    </tr>

<? } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have checked but only first record is shown. I want to display all the records and if user clicks on any particular record then that record should be opened in modal popup.

Comment: Can you give me your JS code. In your code if you goto source it will generate the popup code for the last product in the loop as it is in end of loop. According to my reply it will print popup code for all products. It may be your js isn't initialize properly.